# The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. React Navigator v5

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to use react navigator v5 with typescript but keep getting the following error:
`The navigation prop is missing for this navigator`

I was following the documentation but the documentation code does take an argument for the createStackNavigator function, but it seems like it should take the screens object and stack has to be passed as a child to the navigation container, what am i doing wrong?

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const routes = {
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator(routes)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: solution: need to use the ```@react-navigation/stack``` library instead of the ```react-navigation-stack``` library

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of creating a stack, I would have adviced you to try the new way, check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator)